# Homotopy, Identity

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Show that there is no homotopy between the identity and the function $f:S^1\to S^1$, $(x,y)\mapsto (x,-y)$

Hello,

I have a problem with this task (the task got corrected), because I am not sure, if I get the statement of the task right.

What is meant by the identity here? The function $id: S^1\to S^1$, $(x,y)\mapsto (x,y)$?

I am unsure, because $f$ and $id$ need to have the same domain and codomain. But this is not given, when you observe the identity, or is it?

I would be thankfull, if someone could resolve this question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is this from?

Comment: It is a current homework.

Comment: The question clearly doesn't make sense. the maps have to be maps between the same spaces

Comment: Ah, by now the task was corrected in the online version. I edit it.

Comment: The question about the identity is now resolved. $id: S^1\to S^1$, $(x,y)\mapsto (x,y)$ should be it. But how can I prove this? I have to show that no continuous function $H$ (which holds the necessary conditions) exists. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Are you familiar with covering spaces?

Comment: Yes, I know covering spaces.

Comment: And are you familiar with the homotopy lifting lemma?

Comment: Yes, I think so, even so we did not called it "lifting lemma".

Answer (score 0):

The degree of the identity map is $1$ while the degree of $f$ (a reflection) is $-1$.  Homotopic maps have the same degree so you get the desired result.